# Ruby script transition from Mechanize 2.1 to 1.0 - Selecting a dropdown box

Tags: html, ruby, mechanize

Due to some proxy problems I had with a Ruby script using Mechanize 2.1 I want to convert the script to use Mechanize 1.0. I already made some progress but I am stuck now.

The script crawls the Amazon page to list and multiply all orders in a given timespan. After logging in with the "Sign in" form we head to "Your account" -> Your Orders" and now try to grab this dropdown box:
[image: dropdown box]

This is the HTML code from Amazon:

```
<form id="order-dropdown-form" action="/gp/css/order-history" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="opt" value="ab">
    <label for="orderFilter">
        Date:
    </label>
    <select name="orderFilter" id="orderFilter">
        <option value="select-another" disabled="disabled">
            -Select different orders to view-
        </option>
        <option value="last30" selected="selected">
            Orders placed in the last 30 days
        </option>
        <option value="months-6">
            Orders placed in the past 6 months
        </option>
        <option value="year-2012">
            Orders placed in 2012
        </option>
        <option value="year-2011">
            Orders placed in 2011
        </option>
        (...)
    </select>
   <span class="in-amzn-btn btn-prim-med" unselectable="on"><input type="submit" value="Go"><span></span></span>
</form>
```

The ruby code looks like this:

```
select_form = orders_page.form_with(:id => 'order-dropdown-form')
select_form.field_with(:name => 'orderFilter').options.each do |option|
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with Mechanize 1.0, there is no method "id". So how else can I get that dropdown box?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you need to do. If you need to set the value it's:

```
select_form['orderFilter'] = value
```

If you need to iterate through the options it's more like:

```
orders_page.search('select#orderFilter option').each do |option|
   select_form['orderFilter'] = option[:value]
end
```

Note that doing it this way means that option is a Nokogiri::XML::Node not a Mechanize::Form::Option or whatever. It seems easier to me to do it this way though.